# HP Mini 2133 Display Resolution Issue

Tags: display, display-resolution

I have installed Lubuntu on my old laptop/netbook. I am having issues with the display drivers, it's stuck on one resolution 840x600. That is the only option available.
The laptop ran fine at 1024x600 with Peppermint 7, and Ubuntu 10.somthing.

The card is 
VIA P4M900, VN896, CN896 Chrome9.
Driver: fbdev (unloaded: Vesa)

I at one point uninstalled fbdev and was able to change resolution to several different options but ones I reboot the computer I had a black screen with blinking cursor, I got to a command line reinstall fbdev and back to same resolution issue.

I also tried this:

```
Sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

from

```
uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

to

```
Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

and make it active by running

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot the computer.Then I had black screen with blinking cursor, so I put it back to how it was using a command line and back to same issue with display.

Anyone have any help or ideas?

FYI. The latest Ubuntu, mate, mint all won't work and I have a black screen with a blinking cursor.

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested here worked for me: [How to set up VIA chrome9 screen driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12809/how-to-set-up-via-chrome9-screen-driver)

I've just installed Lubuntu on my old HP Mini (coincidence!) and had the same issue with the screen resolution. Running

```
 sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
```

and rebooting worked for me.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this on? I'm trying to install openchrome on 16.04 but not getting beyond a black screen. FailsafeX doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Likely due to the lack of KMS (Kernel Mode Setting) support, OpenChrome got dropped from default support of the device driver.
You should first install xserver-xorg-video-openchrome package first.

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-openchrome

After that, I recommend updating OpenChrome code by manually compiling the upstream code.

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/openchrome-users/2016-February/007237.html

Regards,

Kevin Brace

The OpenChrome Project maintainer / developer